# What is the meaning of depression student's words?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> To enter into the GED classes, you gotta get an 8.0 or better on the
>   TABE. There's always something wrong with these tests.These tests
>   paint a picture of me with no brain.These tests paint a picture of me
>   and my mother,my whole family, as less than dumb. **Just ugly, black
>   grease to be wiped away** find another job for. Sometimes l wish l was
>   dead.

Somebody explain this highlighted sentences here.

Comment: Please can you reference where the quote is from.

Comment: The text is from the film _Precious (2009)_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The writer is using a metaphor here.

When mechanics finish a job, they usually have dirty, greasy hands.  This messy grease can't be used for anything; the mechanic simply needs to find a wash room and clean it off.

[image]

The student has low self-esteem and low self-worth. He is saying that he doesn't feel useful, he only feels like messy grease that needs to be wiped away.

Comment: +1 Excellent graphic. I might add a word about the significance of the color _black,_ especially given the source of the text.